# Is it possible to work with DateTime value in C++?

Tags: c++, datetime

I'm working with an `API` which offers date and time data as a `double` precision decimal value, which is compatible with the `Windows` `Date/Time` format.  I'm writing a program in `C++` and I'd like to be able to access elements of the data contained within the `double` `Date/Time` value and format them as human readable.  For example take the `Date/Time` value like so `41411.583333` and print a string as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS using C++.  Please can someone explain if/how this can be done?

Comment: There is no direct translation in C or C++ for `double` to any form of date or time format. Traditional standard C library functions use `time_t`, which is typically a 32- or 64-bit integer, representing seconds from 1 of Jan 1970. If your number can be converted to that format, there is plenty of functions about...

Comment: There is a type called "DateTime" in common use in Windows, it doesn't use a double.  There are a couple that do use double, you'll have to narrow it down.

Comment: This looks like the DATE OLE type (which is really a double). It is the distance in days to 12/31/1899 (leaps second aside, and assuming that 1900 has a leap day, which it does not). It is straightforward to convert boost::posix_time::ptime to it.

Comment: @Hans: In Win32?  Don't think so.  There is `SYSTEMTIME`, `FILETIME`, and `DATE` (which is the OLE type Alexandre mentioned) in widespread use in the Windows API.  Limited use of other date/time types for example in DHCP API and SQL API.  With the spelling `DateTime`, perhaps you're thinking of some popular framework which is totally off-topic in a C++ question?

Comment: @Alexandre C.  Are you able to expand a little on that please?  Maybe with a short example of how to work with the `double`  and `boost::posix_time::ptime` to produce a formatted date & time string?  Will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The COleDateTime class (provided in the MFC and ATL libraries) provides everything you need. It includes a Format member function that can print date/time in numerous formats:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1ayhyhk(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: OK thanks @ScottMcP-MVP.  How would I get the `double` `DateTime` value into the `COleDateTime` object?  I see there is a `SetDateTime` member and `ParseDateTime`.  Can't I simply assign the `double` `DateTime` value to the 'COleDateTime` object somehow? The `DateTime` value itself is a decimal number like so: `41411.583333` which I think in this case represents `17th May 2013 14:00hrs`.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the `Boost.Date_Time` library.  [Documentation here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time.html).